# Eclipse throws Launch Error "Selection does not contain main type" on Spring Boot app after Jakarta Migration

Tags: spring-boot, eclipse, jakarta-migration

Problem: While I am trying to run java application on Eclipse, I get Launch Error.

I'm trying to run the code I get a "Launch Error" pop-up. I have migrated my code from javax to jakarta and changed springboot version 2.4.6 to 3.1.0 and java11 to java17 I'm not getting any error while build application.

before migrating code from Java EE to Jakarta EE I was able to run my java application

I have added dependency but still getting launch error.

`<groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId> <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId> <version>9.1.0</version>`

Comment: WARNING: Spring Boot is not part of JEE API (it's part of Spring) and thus adding the whole JEE dependency is per definition wrong. Don't do that. Your real problem needs to be fixed in the IDE project settings.